# Can't get echo from str_replace in function, PHP

Tags: php, echo, str-replace

```
class StringsAndStuff {

    public $repeatedString = "no means no";

    public function stringRepeat($startString, $repeatCount) {
        $this->repeatedString = str_repeat ($startString."</br>", $repeatCount);
    }


    public function stringSwitchWords($multipliedString) {
        $this->repeatedString = str_replace("no", "yes", $multipliedString);        
    }

}

$stuff = new StringsAndStuff;
$stuff->stringRepeat($stuff->repeatedString, 5);
echo $stuff->repeatedString;

//why this won't work?
$stuff->stringSwitchWords(repeatedString);
echo $stuff->repeatedString;
```

I want to get a "yes means yes" string from echo at the end, but it won't work. Please, help me. Thank you for all your answers.

EDIT:
Output:

```
no means no
no means no
no means no
no means no
no means no
repeatedString
```

I think it should be something more like "yes means yes" repeated 5 times.

Comment: While I'm reading through your code, can you go ahead and describe what happens instead? It won't work is something I expect from my mom diagnosing a program bug ;)

Comment: unsure if it is a copy/paste error, but "repeatedString" is not a variable here so its probably throwing an error

$stuff->stringSwitchWords(repeatedString);

Comment: Do you have a constant called `repeatedString` that you're using in `$stuff->stringSwitchWords(repeatedString);`?

Comment: Function stringSwitchWords() is supposed to change words "no" to "yes" in given string.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this instead?  $stuff->stringSwitchWords($stuff->repeatedString);

Answer (score 2):

Your original code:

```
$stuff->stringSwitchWords(repeatedString); // repeatedString is empty
echo $stuff->repeatedString;
```

This should work:

```
echo $stuff->stringSwitchWords($stuff->repeatedString);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/97092)

Comment: @user3262888 You should propably adjust your errorlevel to show notices as well, then you could have caught this yourself: http://ideone.com/M0n66P

Comment: @Potherca: It's best to edit your `php.ini` configuration file and enable the directives. And on SO, I usually suggest folks to add [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) at the very top of their script to enable error reporting :)